# How to use Datapath from a python file to other python files

Tags: python

I have main python file which calls 26 other python files. I want to  define a datapath in the main python file which is to be used by other 26 codes. I tried but could not succeeded.

Here are the main code and one of the other with error which I got while running the main code.
main.py:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

def data_path():
        input_path = '/home/PYTHON-PLOT/2021052512/02B/'
        return input_path
print (data_path())

processes = ('track_final.py')
def run_process(process):
        os.system('python {}'.format(process))

pool = Pool(processes=1)

pool.map(run_process, processes)

#some part of the Other python file:
from hwrf-post-processing import data_path
import glob
import Ngl,Nio,pyproj
import numpy as np
file = sorted(glob.glob(data_path() + 'data_file'))
char = file[0].split('.')
in_year = char[1][0:4]
in_month = char[1][4:6]
in_day = char[1][6:8]
in_hour = char[1][8:10]
std1 = in_year + in_month + in_day

Error:
python: can't open file 't': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'r': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'a': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'c': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'k': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file '_': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'f': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'i': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'n': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'a': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'l': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
/home/test/miniconda3/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in '.'
python: can't open file 'p': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'y': [Errno 2] No such file or directory



#Any help would be greatly appreciated.
```

Comment: What error does your code return?or?

Comment: this is clearly missing code to reproduce the error

Comment: Please see the error@hungcuiga1 AND ti7

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere this is making a list out of a string, likely when you call `pool.map(run_process, processes)`, which leads to the error you see

```py
>>> processes = ('track_final.py')
>>> list(processes)
['t', 'r', 'a', 'c', 'k', '_', 'f', 'i', 'n', 'a', 'l', '.', 'p', 'y']
```

Perhaps you'd be better served by calling `import track_final` and running its main function?

You are confused about how to use multiprocessing's pool and map, which is intended to take an iterable and run each member of it in the pool of processes (which you can think of as a collection of workers each taking from a queue)

Take a look at the example use from the official docs
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers